# idea/direction to build a crawler package for meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm thinking of building a package that make building node crawler easy. I've built crawlers before using tools such as webpack and webdriverjs and all the routing and communication back and forth between bot and server is such a pain to setup every time.

Meteor's way seems much sweeter: no explicit routing, client can just invoke functions and it just works. So I intend to build a helper package that you can depend on to build your own crawler package where you only include a bot.js file, within it you emit events and terminate the bot when you're done like this:

```
var contents=$('.content-to-scrape').html() //getting some contents
Crawler.emit('contents', contents);
Crawler.terminate();
```

And on server side you just have to invoke it like this:

```
Crawler.start('http://somesite.com');
Crawler.on('contents', callback1);
Crawler.on('terminate', callback2);
```

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to build packages to serve browser bot though. Meteor build system doesn't seem to build for anything other than client and server, and it seems quite complex. So I decided to use webpack for packaging a bundle to serve to browser bot. And I guess I could use `WebApp.connectHandlers` to add any routing I need. What I'm wondering though is where to put the bundle file created with webpack such that I could serve it using the connect handler.

Tell me if this is feasible with Meteor or whether I'm headed in the right direction?

Comment: why the down vote? care to explain?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you, but I find it hard to see what your actual question is? It seems like there is a lot of rambling one would need to follow in order to understand what your actual question is (apart from the "right direction" question which is somewhat clear, albeit perhaps a little opinion based).

Comment: @Christian: Perhaps you're right. The ideal answer to this question is probably somewhat opinion based, not a clear cut answer. Is this not the right place to ask such question?

Comment: @Khoi: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/should-we-have-a-subjective-version-of-every-stack-exchange-site ;)

Comment: There should be a place to ask such questions, but... it's hard. http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/stackoverflow-brother-of-type-subjective-or-opinion-base

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you should first take a look at the already built Meteor packages available at github.

These are some of the famous ones, and will give you an insight of what you intend to do:

- https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm
- https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi
- https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS

Then, you should follow this guide https://atmospherejs.com/docs/publishing